# Swift ViewController with TableView in Objc makes Cell hidden

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview

I'm currently testing a little bit with Swift.
What I wanted to do is, to make a ViewController with a tableView in it and display this via objc.But when I add the init my Swift class and want to add the view as a subview in my objc viewcontroller, my cells get hidden once I touched the tableview.

This is my Swift Code:
MainMenuViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

@objc
class MainMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MainMenuTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell");
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK : tableview
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainMenuTableViewCell;

        //cell.icon.image = UIImage(named: "clock")
        cell.menuTitle.text = "test"

        return cell;
    }
}
```

MainMenuTableViewCell.swift

```
class MainMenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    //MARK : properties

    @IBOutlet weak var menuTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and this is how I add the view in ObjC:
ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)ShowMenu:(id)sender
{
    MainMenuViewController *mainMenu = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
    [mainMenu.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.navigationController.navigationBar.height, self.view.width-100, self.view.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:mainMenu.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add it as a child view controller

```
[childController willMoveToParentViewController:rootViewController];
[rootViewController addChildViewController:childController];
[rootViewController.view addSubview:childController.view];
[childController didMoveToParentViewController:rootViewController];
```

Hope this works

Comment: @TdoubleG Your container view controller must associate a child view controller with itself before adding the child's root view to the view hierarchy. This allows iOS to properly route events to child view controllers and the views those controllers manage